# Proving a quadrilateral is an isosceles trapezoid

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, education

**Warning:** You'll probably need pencil and paper to follow this.

Recently I came across the following problem in a middle/high school geometry textbook:

$\ast$

Suppose $\ QUAD\ $ is a quadrilateral with

$(1) \quad \overline{QU}\cong\overline{AD} \quad ,$

$(2) \quad \overline{UA}\not\cong \overline{DQ} \quad , \quad$ and

$(3) \quad \angle Q\ $ supplementary to $\ \angle A \quad .$

Prove that $\ QUAD\ $ is an isosceles trapezoid.

$\ast$

I first managed to prove the theorem drawing a line through $\ U\ $ parallel to $\ \overline{AD}\ $, then extending $\ \overline{QU}\ $ and $\ \overline{AD}\ $ and working with proportions. Needless to say, the proof got a bit involved.

Later I designed a different proof:  Suppose $\ \overline{UA}\ $ and $\ \overline{DQ}\ $ are not parallel; then they meet in a point $\ P\ ,\ $ let's say to the "left" of $\ QUAD\ .\ $ One can now show using $\ (3)\ $ that $\ \triangle PQU \sim \triangle PAD\ ,\ $ which contradicts $\ (1)\ .\ $ So $\ \overline{UA}\ $ is parallel to $\ \overline{DQ}\ ,\ $which basically proves the theorem; property $\ (2)\ $ is there to rule out the case of a rectangle (which I gather is not considered an isosceles trapezoid).

Is there something I'm missing here?  Seems a bit involved/indirect for an elementary geometry problem. Thanks!

Comment: $\angle Q+\angle A=\pi\iff QUAD$ is inscribed. Then we compute inscribed angles to show $\angle UQD=\angle QDA$

Comment: That's lovely! Thank you!